# SQL query counts more data than it exists

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I want to count how many visitors that are from Sweden (based on IP address) by using this SQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(vd.data_country)
FROM visitors_details AS vd
JOIN visitors AS v
ON vd.id_visitor = v.id
WHERE v.id_website = '1'
AND vd.data_country = 'SE'
GROUP BY vd.id_visitor
```

The problem with this SQL query is that it shows 830 visitors that are from Sweden. When I count the Swedish visitors manually from the database, I'll get 671 visitors (I have marked every Swedish visitor in HeidiSQL so I have not miscounted).

If I change `COUNT(vd.data_country)` to `COUNT(DISTINCT vd.data_country)` it only shows 1 visitor.

Here's how the databases looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `visitors` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_website` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `data_ipaddress` text NOT NULL,
  `data_useragent` text NOT NULL,
  `data_referer` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `visitors_details` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_visitor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_permissions` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data_filename` text NOT NULL,
  `data_filename_get` text NOT NULL,
  `data_city` text NOT NULL,
  `data_postalcode` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `data_county` text NOT NULL,
  `data_country` text NOT NULL,
  `data_location` text NOT NULL,
  `data_hostname` text NOT NULL,
  `data_organisation` text NOT NULL,
  `datetime_occurred` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
)

INSERT INTO `visitors` (`id`, `id_website`, `data_ipaddress`, `data_useragent`, `data_referer`)
VALUES(1, 1, '127.0.0.1', '', '')

INSERT INTO `visitors_details` (`id`, `id_visitor`, `id_user`, `id_permissions`, `data_filename`, `data_filename_get`, `data_city`, `data_postalcode`, `data_county`, `data_country`, `data_location`, `data_hostname`, `data_organisation`, `datetime_occurred`)
VALUES(1, 1, 0, 0, 'page-start.php', '-', 'city', 12345, 'county', 'SE', 'loc', 'hostname', 'org', '2015-03-31 18:45:37')
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If the visitor accesses multiple files, each of those is counted separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT id_visitor)` so you don't count a visitor separately for each file they access. And get rid of `GROUP BY vd.id_visitor`.

`COUNT(DISTINCT data_country)` is 1 because you've restricted it to just one country (Sweden).

Comment: Then it only also shows 1 visitor. If I remove `ORDER BY vd.id_visitor` it shows 9 visitors. What should I do to so it shows the right amount of visitors?

Comment: Could you make a sqlfiddle with sample data?

Comment: Ye. If I could. Even if I took "Text to DDL" I got the classic error, "You have an error in your SQL syntax...". I edited my question and added the insert data you'll need.

Comment: You'll need more than 1 row in each table to be able to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Did you forget to put a `;` at the end of each statement in sqlfiddle?

Comment: Nope. I tried to add 2 rows in SQL Fiddle - same error. I didn't removed anything from the generated "Text to DDL". I just added rows

Comment: Well that's just crazy! O.o If I remove `GROUP BY vd.id_visitor` and use `COUNT(vd.data_country)`, I'll get 1 381 visitors. If I change it to `COUNT(DISTINCT id_visitor)`, I'll get 9 visitors. The code on SQL Fiddle shows right though :S Strange. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b055/4/0

Comment: I don't understand your sample data. All the rows in `visitor_details` are the same except the ID. And you only have one row in `visitors`. Shouldn't the count be 1?

Comment: I choose not to insert all the rows (which is over 1 000 with the Swedish visitors and other visitors) and I don't want to show the real data. Yes. I have 49 rows in `visitors` but will only count from `visitors_details`. `v.id_website` only defines the website I gather information from.

Comment: I obviously don't expect you to put everything into the fiddle, but you need to put enough data so that it demonstrates the problem with the number of counts.

Comment: The general reason why queries like this return numbers too large is because there are multiple matches between the two tables, and you don't want to count all those duplicates.

Comment: And the solution is either to use `COUNT(DISTINCT something)` or to join with a subquery that uses `GROUP BY` to get rid of duplicates.